# Type casting of double to String in swift

Tags: swift

```
func getListing(var qty: Int) -> String{
        if(qty < qtyInStock) {
            return title + ", by " + author + " ($" + NSString(format:"%\(price).2d", price) + ")...In Stock"
        }
        else {
            //return NSString(format: "%\(price)d") + author

            return title + ", by " + author + " ($" + NSString(format:"%\(price).2d") + ")...Sold out"
        }
    }
```

Output : The Great Gatsby, by F. Scott Fitzgerald ($          00)...In Stock"

I am unable to get the price value in the output. Also I don't to have an extra spacing in between the $ sign and the price of type double. Can you please help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

Use `%.2f` instead of `%\(price).2d`

Answer (score 1):

You should use NSNumberFormatter to format your numbers. Just create a read-only computed property Double extension as follow:

```
extension Double {
    var currency: String {
        let styler = NSNumberFormatter()
        styler.minimumFractionDigits = 2
        styler.maximumFractionDigits = 2
        styler.numberStyle = .CurrencyStyle
        styler.currencySymbol = "$"
        return styler.stringFromNumber(self)!
    }
}

199.99.currency   // "$199.99"
```